# How can I view or FTP into my Wordpress site hosted on AWS?

Tags: hosting, ftp, amazon

If this is the wrong site for this, I apologize. I am not a Wordpress developer, but I have a small bit of WP experience.

Does anyone know how I could view the file tree of a Wordpress site hosted on AWS? I am trying to migrate a Wordpress page for a non-profit from AWS to another hosting service. Unfortunately, AWS console is clogged with dozens (hundreds?) of non-descriptive product names, and something like viewing your hosted files is not given any intuitive guideposts. I feel like I'm getting warmer with the EC2 console, but I don't see even a FTP server address.

I would like to FTP into the hosted page, or at the very least, view the hosted files.
Can anyone point me to where these tool are hiding in AWS console?

Many thanks.

Comment: Most AWS WP installs are based on Bitnami if I recall correctly and they have atypical permission sets.

Not sure why you're looking for a specific hosted page though unless I misunderstand what you're after.  The easiest migration would be to locate the `wp-content` directory and download it, then export the db as an `.sql` file, the rest of it can stay on AWS.  Install a new WP on the new host import the `.sql`, upload the `wp-content` directory and then work on resolving any broken connections.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this question probably belongs in an AWS SO somewhere.
But yes you're on the right track, you'd most likely look under EC2 for "instances"
If there's only one instance, your life will be easier.
Find the ip address bound to the instance in question.
I would have to guess that both:

- FTP is not enabled on the server,
- FTP is not allowed by AWS firewall policy,

And you will have better success using SFTP but will still probably have some learning to do if the access permissions aren't enabled, you'll need to add a new firewall rule as well as get hold of an access key (pem file).

When I connect from Linux to AWS with SFTP, this is the command used:

```
sftp -o "IdentityFile=my-aws-xyz.pem" ubuntu@ec2-X-Y-Z-ZZ.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

(Replace X,Y, Z with your values)

Comment: I was not able to make this work, mainly due to time constraints and the prior webmaster not speaking much English, so I don't want to accept it as an answer, but thank you for your suggestions.